# How do I make the CheckBox in a CheckBoxList appear on the left of my text?

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I've been looking around but didn't find any members that seemed to let you set this.  Can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<asp:CheckBoxList id="lb1" runat="server" TextAlign="Left">
```

The textAlign determines which side of the check box the text will appear (or `TextAlign="Right"` to answer your question).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried "TextAlign" Attribute of Checkboxlist to manage the text alignment?